# Comments within \pgfplotstableread{...} lead to error

Tags: pgfplotstable, comments, bugs

I use the `\pgfplotstableread{}` command of the `pgfplotstable` package and manually type in a table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
  Col1  Col2
  p0    Text0
  p1    Text1%blabla
  p2    Text2
  p3    Text3
}\mytable

\end{document}
```

There seems to be a bug with comments at the end of rows. With the provided example, I am getting the following error:

> Package pgfplots Error: Table '<inline_table>' appears to have too many columns in line 3: Ignoring 'Text2'. PGFPlots found that the number of columns is larger than the previously determined number of columns. Please verify that every cell entry is separated correctly (use braces {} if necessary. Also verify that column names are plain ASCII.). This error is not critical.

I am not sure what's going on but when I remove `%blabla`, the document compiles just fine. Until now, I thought that comments at the end of lines were "invisible" in Latex.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I'm not a user of `pgfplots`, but what I think is happening is that the `%` is suppressing the line ending, which is needed to make a correct column count.  Try adding a space before the `%`.  (Just a guess; not tested.)

Comment: as Barbara wrote you are hiding the newline character. Try `p1    Text1^^M%blabla`

Comment: It is not true that "comments at the end of lines are invisible". [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537574/119) gives a run down of what happens. In particular, during state "M", the end of line character is converted to a space, if encountered. So the comment character `%` may end up removing a space, if it is not preceded by a space character. // The effect is more pronounced when you are in `\obeylines` where the end of line character is converted to `\par` instead of a space. // Your question is about another context where the presence of the end of line character matters.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! Adding a space before the `%` does not solve the issue but I now understand the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual says that `[row sep=newline]` is fragile, even though it is the default.  You **can** start a line with `%` and the whole line is ignored.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[every column/.style={string type},row sep=\\]{
  Col1  Col2\\
  p0    Text0\\
  p1    Text1\\%blable
  p2    Text2\\
  p3    Text3\\
}\mytable

\pgfplotstabletypeset[every column/.style={string type}]{\mytable}

\end{document}
```